Doubly stochastic gradient descent on pennylane
H = 4+2I⊗X+4I⊗Z−X⊗X+5Y⊗Y+2Z⊗X. I am given this Hamiltonian which I want to minimize using doubly stochastic gradient descent, and the code that I found on pennylane website is:
I = np.identity(2)
X = np.array([[0, 1], [1, 0]])
Y = np.array([[0, -1j], [1j, 0]])
Z = np.array([[1, 0], [0, -1]])

terms = np.array(
    [
    2 * np.kron(I, X),
    4 * np.kron(I, Z),
    -np.kron(X, X),
    5 * np.kron(Y, Y),
    2 * np.kron(Z, X),
    ]
)


@qml.qnode(dev_stochastic, interface="autograd")
def circuit(params, n=None):
    StronglyEntanglingLayers(weights=params, wires=[0, 1])
    idx = np.random.choice(np.arange(5), size=n, replace=False)
    A = np.sum(terms[idx], axis=0)
    return expval(qml.Hermitian(A, wires=[0, 1]))


def loss(params, shots=None):
    return 4 + (5 / 1) * circuit(params, shots=shots, n=1)
cost = []
params = init_params
opt = qml.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.005)

for _ in range(250):
    cost.append(loss(params, shots=100))
    params = opt.step(loss, params, shots=100)

Now, in this code I am unable to understand what is this loss function that we defined in line 20. Please somebody explain.
For more information this is the website: https://pennylane.ai/qml/demos/tutorial_doubly_stochastic/

First, you randomly pick a number called idx:
idx = np.random.choice(np.arange(5), size=n, replace=False)
Using this sampled number, you pick a term from the list terms of Hamiltonian terms. For example, if idx=3, then A=-np.kron(X, X).
Also, you can set up np.random.choice to sample multiple numbers instead of just one. Then, your A is a sum of terms corresponding to the sampled numbers, e.g., if idx = [0,1], then A = 2 * np.kron(I, X) + 4 * np.kron(I, Z)
Finally, you define your loss function:
return 4 + (5 / 1) * circuit(params, shots=shots, n=1)
which is the expected value of A multiplied by 5/1 and plus 4.
This all means that during the optimization loop, a different part of a Hamiltonian is randomly selected and used to compute the expectation value, which is then used to compute gradients.

Thanks.  I still have some doubts not regarding this loss function but what my code is doing, but I think I will write another question because the question is big. It seems I don't get a reply on this question for a long time so when I upload my new question, I will comment here again, so please help me with that.
